# jQuery image hover problems

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm working in jQuery and i'm trying to do something with a mouse over. When i mouse over an image the image will go up and a small text below will show up but how can i do this? when i make a mouse over on the image does the image go up but when i hover the div then the hole thing spaces. Is there a way to stop this?

```
$(".aImgContainer img").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({"transform":"translateY(-40px)"});
});

$(".aImgContainer img").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css({"transform":"translateY(0px)"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mRHa5/

Comment: Please post a complete code example so we can see exactly what you're doing and recreate the issue. Examples on jsFiddle.net help us help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mRHa5/

Comment: Do you want the image slide up effect or fade is fine?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do when you mouseover?

Comment: the image needs to go up so that you can see the div below but when your mouse stands at the div when the img is hoverd will the hole thing go up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the top position rather than translate? I had to tweak a couple css rules too.

```
$(".colofoonFoto").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').css({"top":"-40px"});
});

$(".colofoonFoto").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('img').css({"top":"0"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/carasin/AraQT/2/

Answer (score 2):

There you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRHa5/1/)

I've changed the mouse events to be on the container `.colofoonFoto` instead of the img. the problem was that when you hovered the image and it went up - your mouse was no longer on it

Comment: is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes but i'm trying it now at my project and it still is doing weard things

Comment: maybe you have some more css in your project that causes conflicts

Comment: no all the css in the jsFiddle project is exact the same as in my project. i copied and pasted it

Comment: mmm do you have an online link?

Comment: you didn't copy my javascript correcty.. forgot `.find('img')`